# Alias to python module

Tags: python

I have some python module, that I import as:

```
from mygraph.draw import pixel
```

The file structure looks like that:

```
mygraph/
    __init__.py
    draw.py
```

and `draw.py` contains `def pixel()`

Now, I want to add another function, `line()`, and I want to import it as

```
from mygraph.draw import line
```

I can simply add `line` to `draw.py`. But, I would like to have `line()` in a separate file `line.py` and not mess with draw.py. But, if I place it in a separate file, it will be imported as

```
from mygraph.line import line
```

and that is not what I want...

Is it possible to "alias" somehow the `line.py` so it is visible in `draw` module, but is in separete file? I thought about adding a dummy function in `draw`

```
def line():
    return real_line.line()
```

but in this case I won't have a "docstring" from the original `line`, and I will loose some performance on calling the real line function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your `draw.py` module:

```
from line import line
```

and you should be able to invoke it as `mygraph.draw.line`, and import it the way you wanted.

I do this a lot in my `__init__.py` files: expose the primary API this way.

Answer (score 4):

Structure like this will make more sense for you:

```
mygraph/
    __init__.py
    draw/
        __init__.py
        pixel.py
        line.py
```

Then in `draw/__init__.py` you would have code like this:

```
from mygraph.draw.pixel import pixel, redpixel, greenpixel
from mygraph.draw.line import line, redline, greenline
```

And it is convenient to use your package:

```
from mygraph.draw import redpixel, redline
```

**Be aware of circular imports.** For example if `line` needs `pixel` to work, and you do `import pixel` in `line.py`, you cannot do `import line` in `pixel.py`, because you are running to into circular imports.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way would be to add the following lines to `draw.py`:

```
from line import line
```

In this case you can import `line` from `draw.py` too.